# How to redirect another component when canActivate returns false?

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

Hi I am using routing in angular 5 and I have a login path that uses canActivate property

can I redirect to another path when canActivate is false?
I don't want user to see the login page if he/she is logged in.

here main service returns false if user is logged in

```js
{
    path: 'login',
    component: RegisterLoginComponent,
    canActivate: [MainService]
}
```

Comment: I've always redirected in the guard if the user doesn't have access. Not aware of another way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to protect your default path with a [Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) and redirect to `/login` from there if authentication fails.

```js
/* AuthService */
isLoggedIn(): boolean {
  // check if user is logged in
  return isUserLoggedIn;
}

/* AuthGuard */
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
...
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  // check if user is logged in
  const loggedIn: boolean = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
  // if not, redirect to /login
  if (!loggedIn) {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
  return loggedIn;
}
```

**Note**: If you want to control where you redirect to, you have access to the url that the user was trying to access under `route.url`. You can check its value and then navigate to specific url, instead of always to '/login'.

Here's a quick sample code that does this redirection with asynchronous code as well. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-guard-redirect?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth-with-redirect.guard.ts

Answer (score 0):

Redirect in login service if credentials match

```
 this.authService.signin(user)
  .subscribe(
    data => {

      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
    },
    error => console.error(error)
  )
```